# Android pass Boolean object instead of primitive in Bundle

Tags: java, android

I want to pass Boolean object instead of primitive boolean with putBoolean (or with some other method) because I need also to know if there was either a value assigned or no.

Now I have two Checkboxes. First one verifies if the second one will be enabled and will be a possibility to check a value (true or false) otherwise it will be null because no value was assigned by putBoolean. I hope you understand what I mean.

This is my code.

```
private Bundle filter(EditText dateFromFilter, EditText dateToFilter, EditText opponentStationFilter, boolean ifCorrectness, CheckBox correctness) {
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    (...)
    if (ifCorrectness) arguments.putBoolean("correctnessFilter", correctness.isChecked());
    return arguments;
}
```

So when ifCorrectness (this is .isChecked from first Checkbox) was false, I do not want to put any boolean value, so I want arguments.getBoolean("correctnessFilter") to be null.

And finally later in another method this value is being get:

```
protected HistorySearchCriteria prepareSearchCriteria(Context context, Bundle arguments) {
    HistorySearchCriteria searchCriteria = new HistorySearchCriteria();
    if (arguments != null) {
        final Boolean correctnessCriteria = arguments.getBoolean("correctnessFilter");
        searchCriteria.setCorrectnessFilter(correctnessCriteria);
    } 
    return searchCriteria;
}
```

And now in this method when this checkbox wasn't set by `arguments.putBoolean("correctnessFilter", correctness.isChecked())` I want `arguments.getBoolean("correctnessFilter");` to be null. How to achieve that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you add the Class you're using this in, and confirm if both the checkboxes are in the same layout?

Comment: To be honest I can not add too much code because it is a property of my company I work in. Yes, those Checklboxes are in the same layout. I guess the only problem is in arguments.getBoolean("correctnessFilter") which returns primitive boolean (which cannot be null) instead of object Boolean (which can be null). I am looking for workaround or another similar way to achieve what I want.

Comment: `To be honest I can not add too much code because it is a property of my company I work in.` that should be irrelevant, you should be able to create a complete working example without using any of your actual code, right ? nothing prevents you from writing basic methods and code up to the point where others can recreate this problem

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code of `Boolean` you'll see that it implements `Serializable` :

```
public final class Boolean implements java.io.Serializable,
                                      Comparable<Boolean>
```

So you can use `putSerializable` method of bundle.

For example:

```
Boolean b = null;
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("correctnessFilter", b);
```

And on the other side get it back from the bundle & cast it to `Boolean`. Use according to your use case:

```
Boolean result = (Boolean) bundle.getSerializable("correctnessFilter");
        if (result != null) {
            Log.d("Tag-value", result.toString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you confirmed the checkboxes are in the same layout, why do you want to use bundles to maintain a `boolean` to check if it is checked or not instead of using a `listener`.

Try something like:

```
checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
           if (isChecked) {
               // your code here when it's checked
           } else {
               // your code here when it's not checked/unchecked 
           }
       }
   }
);
```

That should work if everything you're trying to perform is in a single `activity`!

Answer (score -1):

You cannot store a null in Bundle as far as I know, but there is a simpler solution to this than all of that.

As you say here

> So when ifCorrectness (this is .isChecked from first Checkbox) was false, I do not want to put any boolean value, so I want arguments.getBoolean("correctnessFilter") to be null.

So the answer is right in front of you, only store it in `arguments` when it is `true` and by default it will be `null` otherwise and infact you are already doing that I believe.

```java
if (ifCorrectness){
 arguments.putBoolean("correctnessFilter", correctness.isChecked());
}
```

As you are already only storing it when `ifCorrectness` is true so by default when you try to get it when it is `false` you will receive null only.